# OpenJDK 11 use TLS 1.2 in JDBC connection string

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

My remote MySQL server only accepts connections over TLS 1.2. How do i select protocol version in JDBC (OpenJDK 11)?

```
SQL State: 28000
java.sql.SQLException: TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements
for this server. Please use a higher TLS version and retry.
```

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

I've tried adding `enabledSslProtocolSuites` to my connection string but to no avail.

```
jdbc:mysql://{server}.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/{database_name}?
  serverTimezone=Australia/Melbourne&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&enabledSslProtocolSuites=TLSv1.2
```

Adding `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2" -Djavax.net.debug=all` when launching `mvn exec:java` reveals attempts to Client Hello with TLS **1.1**.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0C|azuremysqltest.App.main()|
2020-08-31 09:16:34.400 UTC|ClientHello.java:653|
Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.1",
  "random"              : "0D 94 D2 90 A7 C0 ...",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : ...
```

Comment: Please try `enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2` instead of `enabledSslProtocolSuites...` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55129768/592355 ...)

Comment: Excellent, that works, thanks! Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can (obviously) select the TLS version for the mysql driver (java vendor independently) via the `enabledTLSProtocols` property ([8.0 reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html#cj-conn-prop_enabledTLSProtocols)):

> - enabledTLSProtocols
>
> ---
>
> If **"useSSL"** is set to **"true"**, **overrides** the **TLS protocols enabled** for use on the underlying SSL sockets. This may be used to **restrict connections to specific TLS versions**. |Since|Version 8.0.8|

In your case the value `=TLSv1.2` approved working. Sorry I can't find the reference on the (exact) value(s) of this property, but we can further investigate/get supported ssl protocol versions [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634102/592355).